# Problems in uiview hide and show

Tags: ios, user-interface

Actually i have to make a view appear and disappear once the button is clicked.please tell me the specific code to make it done

```
happyView=[[UIView alloc]init];
happyView.frame=CGRectMake(MainView.frame.size.width*0.26,CGRectGetHeight(happyBtn.frame)*2.2, CGRectGetWidth(MainView.frame)/1.6, CGRectGetHeight(MainView.frame)/3);
happyView.layer.cornerRadius=8.0;
happyView.layer.borderWidth=0.5;
happyView.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor grayColor]CGColor];
[MainView addSubview:happyView];    

LettingGo=[[UIButton alloc]init];
LettingGo.frame=CGRectMake(happyView.frame.size.width*0.01,happyView.frame.size.height*0.1, CGRectGetWidth(happyView.frame)/1.05, 50);
[LettingGo setTitle:@"Letting go of negativity" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
LettingGo.titleLabel.numberOfLines=2;
LettingGo.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
[LettingGo setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.400f green:0.737f blue:0.761f alpha:1.00f]];
[happyView addSubview:LettingGo];

LivingPresent=[[UIButton alloc]init];
LivingPresent.frame=CGRectMake(happyView.frame.size.width*0.01,LettingGo.frame.size.height*1.4, CGRectGetWidth(happyView.frame)/1.05, 40);
[LivingPresent setTitle:@"Living in the present" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
LivingPresent.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
[LivingPresent setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.400f green:0.737f blue:0.761f alpha:1.00f]];
[happyView addSubview:LivingPresent];
happyView.hidden=YES;

...

- (void)tapHappy:(id)selector {
    happyView.hidden=NO;
}
```

Comment: You should explain your requirement clearly ?

Comment: @sanjeet I thought it was explained clearly enough? He needed to know how to assign a method to a button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIButton has a method addTarget to call a method when an action has happened on the button

```
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tapHappy:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This will search the class it's in "self" for a method "tapHappy:" when the user lifts their finger from the button "UIControlEventTouchUpInside"

Obviously you can change these values to suit your needs

But that should be what you're looking for I think..

And then maybe change the tapHappy method so it isn't ALWAYS setting YES to the hidden property... maybe something like

```
happyView.hidden=!happyView.hidden;
```

That will toggle it on and off

Comment: @Arun Glad I could help! You should upvote this answer if it helped so others will see it easier

Answer (score 0):

When you call `tapHappy` method check weather your happyView hidden or not.

```
UIButton * yourButton=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    yourButton.frame=CGRectMake(YOUR_FRAME);
    [yourButton setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tapHappy:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [yourButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.400f green:0.737f blue:0.761f alpha:1.00f]];
    [YourView addSubview:yourButton];




-(void)tapHappy:(id)selector{
    if(happyView.hidden)
        happyView.hidden = NO;
    else
        happyView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: pls don't comment these things. pls maintain the Stackoverflow rule